# setting migrate scripts to current

Tags: flyway

scenario: 
I have two databases db1 && db2.  I have the following migrate scripts v1.sql, v2.sql, v3.sql.  db1 is actively being worked on so it's migrate includes v1,v2,v3.  db2 only has v1 migration applied to it.  I'm trying to use flyway to manage my migrations.

I have found that setting up db2 is easy with flyway by doing the following.  Set v1 as baseline and then run mvn flyway:migrate.  BAM

db1 is a different story.  I can't really follow the same steps as I did with db2.  How do I build the schema_version table with v1..v3 scripts already complete?  Do I still set v1 as baseline and then run migrate with some weird parameter that v2,v3 have already been executed?

Answer (score 0):

Set v3 as the baseline. This is what baseline is for: tagging existing DBs.

Comment: with all 3 .sql files sitting in the migrations folder how would you tell baseline to use v3 rather than v1?  I see baselineVersion.. but that seems like what it puts in the db as whatever version you put in

Comment: Yes, that's what you need: baselineVersion=3